# Onnx Model Save Problem 'tuple' object has no attribute 'graph'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, onnx

In the process of changing the keras model to onnx, I found error "'tuple' object has no attribute 'graph'"by using Onnx
My code is below, Please help me

```
import tf2onnx
import onnx
from tensorflow.python.keras import models

model = models.load_model("model.h5")   

onnx_model = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model, opset=13)

onnx.save(model, 'test.onnx')
```

"C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\OnnxTest\main.py", line 13, in 
onnx.save(onnx_model, 'test.onnx')
File "C:\Users\bigpicture\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\onnx_*init*_.py", line 195, in save_model
proto = write_external_data_tensors(proto, basepath)
File "C:\Users\test\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\onnx\external_data_helper.py", line 276, in write_external_data_tensors
for tensor in _get_all_tensors(model):
File "C:\Users\test\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\onnx\external_data_helper.py", line 207, in _get_initializer_tensors
yield from _get_initializer_tensors_from_graph(onnx_model_proto.graph)
**AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'graph'**

Answer (score 0):

tf2onnx.convert.from_keras returns 2 values.  you are accepting just 1 return value, and therefore the method is returning both values as a single tuple. This small change of adding a comma and underscore to receive and ignore the extra return values will fix the problem:

onx, _ = tf2onnx.convert.from_keras(model)

More info: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-return-multiple-values-use-only-one